# Running Excel VBA query with nested subqueries and union against IBM DB2

Tags: excel, vba, db2

I have a query that looks like this:

```
select
    tvb.oppdrag_Gjelder_id,
    tvd.BEREGNINGS_ID,
    tvd.KODE_KLASSE, 
    tvd.KONTOSTRENG,
    tvd.DATO_FAKTISK_FOM,
    tvd.DATO_FAKTISK_TOM,
    integer(tvd.BELOP) as BELØP,
    tvb.DATO_BEREGNET
from
    os314t1.t_vent_detalj as tvd
    inner join os314t1.t_vent_beregning as tvb on tvb.BEREGNINGS_ID = tvd.BEREGNINGS_ID
where
    tvd.BEREGNINGS_ID in (
        select distinct(tvb3.BEREGNINGS_ID) as BEREGNINGS_ID 
        from os314t1.t_vent_beregning as tvb3
            inner join os314t1.T_VENT_STOPPNIVAA as tvsn3 on tvb3.BEREGNINGS_ID = tvsn3.BEREGNINGS_ID
            inner join os314t1.T_VENT_STOPPSTATUS as tvss3 on tvss3.BEREGNINGS_ID = tvb3.BEREGNINGS_ID
            inner join os314t1.T_VENT_DETALJ as tvd3 on tvd3.BEREGNINGS_ID = tvb3.BEREGNINGS_ID
            and tvss3.LOPENR = 9999
            and tvss3.KODE_VENTESTATUS not in ('KORR')
            and tvsn3.KODE_FAGOMRAADE in ('TBKRAV')
            and tvd3.KODE_KLASSE = 'TBKRAVUT'
            and tvsn3.dato_periode_fom between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-01'
    )
    and tvd.KODE_KLASSE not in ('FSKTSKAT','TBMOTOBS')
union all
select 
    tvb.oppdrag_Gjelder_id,
    tvd.BEREGNINGS_ID,
    tvd.KODE_KLASSE, 
    tvd.KONTOSTRENG,
    tvd.DATO_FAKTISK_FOM,
    tvd.DATO_FAKTISK_TOM,
    integer(tvd.BELOP) as BELØP, tvb.DATO_BEREGNET
from
    os314t1.t_vent_detalj as tvd
    inner join os314t1.t_vent_beregning as tvb on tvb.BEREGNINGS_ID = tvd.BEREGNINGS_ID
where
    tvd.BEREGNINGS_ID in (
        select distinct(tvb2.BEREGNINGS_ID) as BEREGNINGS_ID 
        from os314t1.t_vent_beregning as tvb2
            inner join os314t1.T_VENT_STOPPNIVAA as tvsn2 on tvb2.BEREGNINGS_ID = tvsn2.BEREGNINGS_ID
            inner join os314t1.T_VENT_STOPPSTATUS as tvss2 on tvss2.BEREGNINGS_ID = tvb2.BEREGNINGS_ID
                and tvsn2.TYPE_BILAG = 'E'
                and tvss2.LOPENR = 9999
                and tvss2.KODE_VENTESTATUS not in ('KORR')
                and tvsn2.dato_periode_fom between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-01'
                and tvsn2.KODE_FAGOMRAADE not in ('UFORESPK')
    )
    and tvd.KODE_KLASSE not in ('UFOREUT')
```

It runs just fine in Squirrel SQL client, but when I try to run in in my VBA code, it throws the error:

> Run-time error '-2147217900 (8004e14) ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD SELECT.
>   TOKEN SKIP OPTIMIZE FOR FETCH, EXCEPT MINUS UNION 
>   WAS EXPECTED SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLCODE: -199

I have tried to google an answer to this, but have not succeeded. Anyone have any idea what's wrong, since this works in my SQL client?

Using Excel 2010, and "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2" driver for the connection.

The VBA code is as follows:

'*** DEL 1 - Hente EO-vedtak fra PESYS ***

```
Application.StatusBar = "Henter EO-vedtak... Vennligst vent!"

Dim SQLquery As String 'Variabel som holder SQL spørringen
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection 'Oppretter en databasekobling
Dim MyRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset 'Dette er et array som holder på dataene du henter med SQL'en
Dim teller As Integer 'Teller antall kolonner i MyRecordset
ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;Password=Password;User ID=Username;Data Source=url_here" 'Tilkoblingsstrengen for databasen

Conn.Open ConnectionString 'Åpner tilkobling til databasen

Sheets("SQL").Select
Range("A53:A62").Select

'Bygger opp SQL'en, linje for linje

For Each c In Selection
SQLquery = SQLquery & c.Value & vbCrLf
Next c

MyRecordset.Open SQLquery, Conn 'Åpner et array (MyRecordset) og kjører aktuell SQL streng ved hjelp av den åpne tilkoblingen (Conn)

'Pynter arket med overskrifter fra MyRecordset

Sheets("EO-vedtak PESYS").Select

For teller = 0 To MyRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
Sheets("EO-vedtak PESYS").Cells(1, teller + 1).Value = MyRecordset.Fields(teller).Name
Next

Sheets("EO-vedtak PESYS").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset MyRecordset 'Skriver resultatsettet i A2 og nedover

MyRecordset.Close 'Lukker array
Conn.Close 'Lukker databasetilkoblingen

Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select

Application.StatusBar = "EO-vedtak fullført!"
```

'*** DEL 2 - Hente EO-beregninger med beløp ***

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=DB2OLEDB.1;Network Transport Library=TCPIP;Network Address=url_here;Network Port=Port_number_here;Initial Catalog=OS314T1;Package Collection=NULLID;Default Schema=OS314T1;User ID=Username;Password=Password;" 'Tilkoblingsstrengen for databasen

Conn.Open ConnectionString 'Åpner tilkobling til databasen

Sheets("SQL").Select
Range("A3:A49").Select

'Bygger opp SQL'en, linje for linje

For Each c In Selection
SQLquery = SQLquery & c.Value & vbCrLf
Next c

MyRecordset.Open SQLquery, Conn 'Åpner et array (MyRecordset) og kjører aktuell SQL streng ved hjelp av den åpne tilkoblingen (Conn)

'Pynter arket med overskrifter fra MyRecordset

Sheets("EO beregninger med beløp").Select

For teller = 0 To MyRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
Sheets("EO beregninger med beløp").Cells(1, teller + 1).Value = MyRecordset.Fields(teller).Name
Next

Sheets("EO beregninger med beløp").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset MyRecordset 'Skriver resultatsettet i A2 og nedover

MyRecordset.Close 'Lukker array
Conn.Close 'Lukker databasetilkoblingen

Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select

Application.StatusBar = "Innhenting av data fullført!"
```

*****

It throws the error in the second database query.

Comment: Have you checked the content of your string `SQLquery`? Put a statement `Debug.Print SQLquery` before you issue the `Open` statement.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks for the tip. Have tried a msgbox with the query, but perhaps the debug.print shows it better..

Comment: You can cut&Paste is from there, and issue it for example to Squirrel SQL.